# Just installed Eclipse Helios (eclipse-jee-helios-SR1-win32-x86_64), but I keep getting errors

Tags: java, eclipse

I just installed  Eclipse Helios  (eclipse-jee-helios-SR1-win32-x86_64). Whenever I run it, it shows an error telling me to check the log file. The log file has this:

```
!SESSION 2021-11-11 22:27:35.389 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=M20100909-0800
java.version=17.0.1
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_CA
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product -XXMaxPermSize 256m
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product -XXMaxPermSize 256m
    
!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2021-11-11 22:27:35.540
!MESSAGE error loading hook: org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.BaseHookConfigurator
!STACK 0
java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make protected void java.net.URLClassLoader.addURL(java.net.URL) accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.net" to unnamed module @22f71333
    ....
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:574)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1407)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1383)
    
!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2021-11-11 22:27:35.572
!MESSAGE Startup error
!STACK 1
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.BaseStorage.initialize(org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.BaseAdaptor)" because "this.storage" is null
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.BaseAdaptor.initializeStorage(BaseAdaptor.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.initialize(Framework.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.<init>(Framework.java:157)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.startup(EclipseStarter.java:286)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:175)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at ...
```

How do I resolve this?

Comment: Helios SR1, which was released literally 11 years ago, is not compatible with a version of Java that came out two months ago. You must use a newer version, preferably the current one.

Comment: Helios is 11 years and 21 releases old, Java 8 is probably the last release it would run on. If you want to use Java 17 you need the latest Eclipse 2021-09

Comment: Like @greg-449 said you need the latest version of eclipse. You can download it from https://eclipse.org . If you are using Java-17 install java 17 plugin for eclipse .

Comment: Many thanks @nitind, greg-449 and JFan's reply. I am new here. I was following on an e-book to download the helio eclipse. I will try the new one you recommended.

Comment: @nitind, I don't understand why anyone didn't post an answer

Comment: @HoRn - Because nobody thought it was worth the effort when this can be answered in comments.